# Is it possible in Hibernate? and how?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am looking for solution for fetching data from 2 different table based on table type and reference key, plz look at following sample table structure and entity classes.

Tables

```
1**Type**
    (ID, TableName // Value for TableName can be 'TableA' or 'TableB')

2**TableA**
  ( ID, NameForA)

3**TableB**
   (ID, NameForB)

4**TableMain**
   (ID, Name, TypeID (foreign key of Type table), DataID (can be reference of TableA or TableB))
```

Entity Classes Structure

```
Class Abstract Model{ int ID; } // Model is base class, holds data of ID field and is parent for all entity classes

Class Type extends Model{String TableName;}

Class TableA extends Model{String NameForA;}

Class TableB extends Model{String NameForB;}

Class TableMain extends Model{
String Name;
Type type;
Model data; // can be TableA class or TableB based on Type
}
```

What i am looking for is, TableMain class has field 'data' it can be object of TableA or TableB class , it will decided based on 'Type' which holds tableName if table name is 'TableA' then data will be instance of TableA class or if tableName is 'TableB' the data will be instance of TableB.

I know its not a good practice, but I already have big Database structure and i cannot change it. so this is the only way i have to solve it.

is anybody can help me, how to make it work with hibernate or any other way? or is it possible  to populate data through hibernate automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using PostgreSQL you can easyly inherit Database-Tables:

```
Create Table model(...);
Create Table type(...) inherits model;
```

To fit the Java

```
public class Model{...}
public class Type extends Model{...}
```

(Try eNexus DB Designer ([enexus dbd](http://www.heise.de/download/enexus-db-designer-1180411.html)) also.)

Comment: But the SQL inhirate is only on Table-Structure! Rowset of "model" and "type" differs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I have database in Oracle and I cannot change it, I want to make it work with Hibernate.

Comment: Oracle can inherits like PostgreSQL (or PostgreSQL like Oracle) :D